# Referenced assembly FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll has assembly level attribute but no public type provider classes were found

Tags: sql-server, f#, f#-interactive

How to make [SQLProvider](http://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) work in F#? I followed their steps but had few errors.

1. I run `PM> Install-Package SQLProvider`
2. Create a new .fsx script file
3. Load the dll `#r @"C:\src\FSharpDB\DBTest\packages\SQLProvider.1.2.10\lib\net472\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"`

At that stage, I have this warning:

> Referenced assembly
> 'C:\src\FSharpDB\DBTest\packages\SQLProvider.1.2.10\lib\net472\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll'
> has assembly level attribute
> 'Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices.TypeProviderAssemblyAttribute'
> but no public type provider classes were found

If I continue and try to run the example script, it can't recongnised SqlDataProvider:

```
#r @"C:\src\FSharpDB\DBTest\packages\SQLProvider.1.2.10\lib\net472\FSharp.Data.SqlProvider.dll"
open FSharp.Data.Sql

type Sql = SqlDataProvider<
            Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.MSSQLSERVER,
            "Server=myServer;Database=myDB;Trusted_Connection=True;">
```

Error:

> The type 'SqlDataProvider' is not defined.

Am I missing anything?

**Edit:**
As asked in the comments below, more information on the project configuration

App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

packages.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="FSharp.Core" version="6.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="SQLProvider" version="1.2.10" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.IO" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Net.Http" version="4.3.4" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Runtime" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms" version="4.3.1" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives" version="4.3.0" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates" version="4.3.2" targetFramework="net48" />
  <package id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.5.0" targetFramework="net48" />
</packages>
```

Comment: What's the target framework of your project?

Comment: .NETFramework,Version=v4.8

Comment: After skimming [this issue](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/10323), I solved a similar issue by updating to FSharp.Data 6.0.2. I don't know whether it's a fix or a workaround, though.